# REST and DocumentDB

Tags: c#, rest, azure-cosmosdb

I am creating a Xamarin Android application and I want to use DocumentDB, but unfortunately it's impossible to use Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB NuGet package, and it seems the only way is to use REST.

How can I use REST for receiving, updating, adding data to DocumentDB with C#?

Comment: Can you post any code you have so far?

Comment: Grab your favorite REST client library and hit the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn781481.aspx). The thing most folks find the most tricky is getting the authentication base64 encoding correct but there are a few good SO answers on that.

Answer (score 1):

There is a giant knowledge base about this. You should read it:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn781481.aspx

They are also referencing a Github repository that contains examples on how to interact with that REST interface. It's really easy. Just start out by copying chunks of the code and adjust them to your needs:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-dotnet/tree/master/samples/rest-from-.net

The code is well commented and explains all the steps in detail.